# If a condition is ever met I want to run a loop permanently

Tags: programming, loop

I am trying to run an LED to do SOS in morse code if a temperature is over 20 C and motion is detected, but I want it to continue doing SOS even after the motion goes away or the temperature comes down.

Right now it simply does SOS 1 time and stops.

(sorry if coding is messy)

```
   int counter;
   int motion = 0;


   void setup()
  {

    {Serial.begin(9600);
     pinMode(4, INPUT);
     pinMode(0, OUTPUT);
     pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
     pinMode(1, INPUT);
     digitalWrite(0, HIGH);

     }
  }

    void loop()
   {

   int sensorA0Value = analogRead(A0);
   float voltage = sensorA0Value * (5.00 / 1023.00);
   Serial.print("Voltage: ");
   Serial.print(voltage);



   float temp = (voltage -.5)*100;
   Serial.print("| Temp: ");
   Serial.print(temp);
   Serial.println(" Celcius|");

   motion = digitalRead(4);

   if(motion == HIGH)
    {Serial.println("Motion Detected");}
   if(motion == LOW)
     {Serial.println("No Motion");}


   if(motion == HIGH && temp > 30) 
     {
     digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
     delay(300);
     digitalWrite(2, LOW);
     delay(300);
     digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
     delay(300);
     digitalWrite(2, LOW);
     delay(300);

     digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
     delay(600);
     digitalWrite(2, LOW);
     delay(600);
     digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
     delay(600);
     digitalWrite(2, LOW);
     delay(600);
     digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
     delay(600);
     digitalWrite(2, LOW);

     delay(600);
     digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
     delay(300);
     digitalWrite(2, LOW);
     delay(300);
     digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
     delay(300);
     digitalWrite(2, LOW);
     delay(300);
     digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
     delay(300);
     digitalWrite(2, LOW);
     delay(1000);

   }
     else {
     digitalWrite(2, LOW);

     }
   delay(1000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `while`-loop like this:

```
if(motion == HIGH && temp > 20) {
  while(true){
   SosMethod();
   }
}
```

to clean everything up, then outside your `void loop()` you declare your `SOSMethod()`

```
void loop() {
 ... .
 }

 void SosMethod(){
 your-led-code-with-delays 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is your SOS code:

```
if(motion == HIGH && temp > 30) 
{
 digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
 delay(300);
 digitalWrite(2, LOW);
 delay(300);
 digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
 delay(300);
 digitalWrite(2, LOW);
 delay(300);

 digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
 delay(600);
 digitalWrite(2, LOW);
 delay(600);
 digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
 delay(600);
 digitalWrite(2, LOW);
 delay(600);
 digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
 delay(600);
 digitalWrite(2, LOW);

 delay(600);
 digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
 delay(300);
 digitalWrite(2, LOW);
 delay(300);
 digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
 delay(300);
 digitalWrite(2, LOW);
 delay(300);
 digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
 delay(300);
 digitalWrite(2, LOW);
 delay(1000);
}
```

Step 1: I think you want to send the first S (.-.-.-.-) as 3 sequences instead of 2 sequence, so the code is:

```
if(motion == HIGH && temp > 30) 
{
 digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
 delay(300);
 digitalWrite(2, LOW);
 delay(300);
 digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
 delay(300);
 digitalWrite(2, LOW);
 delay(300);
 digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
 delay(300);
 digitalWrite(2, LOW);
 delay(300);

 digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
 delay(600);
 digitalWrite(2, LOW);
 delay(600);
 digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
 delay(600);
 digitalWrite(2, LOW);
 delay(600);
 digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
 delay(600);
 digitalWrite(2, LOW);

 delay(600);
 digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
 delay(300);
 digitalWrite(2, LOW);
 delay(300);
 digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
 delay(300);
 digitalWrite(2, LOW);
 delay(300);
 digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
 delay(300);
 digitalWrite(2, LOW);
 delay(1000);
}
```

Step 2: Reduce the duplicate code (each 6 sequences of digitalWrite and delay), you will get:

```
if(motion == HIGH && temp > 30) 
{
  send(300);
  send(600);
  send(300);
  delay(1000);
}

void send(int delayTime)
{
   for (length = 0; length < 3; length++)
   {
      digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
      delay(delayTime);
      digitalWrite(2, LOW);
      delay(600);
   }
}
```

Than you want to fix your problem to keep it sending
Instead of

```
if(motion == HIGH && temp > 30) 
{
  send(300);
  send(600);
  send(300);
  delay(1000);
}
```

Use

```
while ((motion == HIGH) && (temp > 30))
{
  send(300);
  send(600);
  send(300);
  delay(1000);
}
```

For easy reading, I always use parenthesis around equal conditional operator (like ==, >).
The variables motion and temp will not be changed in the while loop, so you can use a while here. It is assumed that the variables are not changed in an interrupt.

Comment: In this instance, `while (condition)` is indeed equivalent to `if (condition) while (true)`. The later, however, clearly exposes the intent of the programmer, whereas the former is very likely to cause confusion.

Answer (score 0):

This may be unrelated to the actual question but... your Morse timings
are completely messed up. The standard timings are:

```
element         duration
------------------------
dot                 1
dash                3
interelement gap    1
intercharacter gap  3
interword gap       7
```

where the time unit is the duration of a dot. A correctly timed SOS can
be implemented as follows:

```
const uint32_t DOT_TIME = 150;  // 8 words per minute

void dot() {
    digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
    delay(1 * DOT_TIME);
    digitalWrite(2, LOW);
    delay(1 * DOT_TIME);
}

void dash() {
    digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
    delay(3 * DOT_TIME);
    digitalWrite(2, LOW);
    delay(1 * DOT_TIME);
}

void send_sos() {
    dot(); dot(); dot();
    dash(); dash(); dash();
    dot(); dot(); dot();
    delay(6 * DOT_TIME);  // interword gap
}
```

Notice that there are no intercharacter gaps within SOS, as this is a
[procedural signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosigns_for_Morse_code), transmitted with no letter boundaries. It
is *not* a three-letter word. The last delay is written as
`6 * DOT_TIME` as there is already a one `DOT_TIME` delay at the end of
the function `dot()`.